# How to change Android cameras properties?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm searching for a place in Android (Kitkat 4.4) source code where I can find the camera properties and change them, specifically where `ro.camera.0.devname` is defined.

I searched for **.prop* files under the Android source code that I have (it's private, so I can't really share it) but I didn't find any place where the devname is defined (in general is should be defined as `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video1`)

Is there anyone that knows where such definitions should be?

Comment: FWIW, I looked at a couple of devices (Nexus 5, Nexus 10) and didn't see that property defined.  So looking in AOSP sources may not be fruitful.  (BTW, KitKat is 4.4.)  Such properties are often defined in `/system/build.prop`, which is generated by the build system.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I care because I want to change camera HAL implementation.

Comment: @fadden, I didn't find any .prop file in my repo...

Comment: Generated prop files only appear in the "out" directory, after a build.

Comment: @fadden, I didn't see any camera related properties in any prop file generated after the build under the out directory. But the answer can be seen below (it's inside one of the .mk files)

Comment: That's where it comes *from*.  It still has to end up on the device.  The usual mechanism for doing that is for the build system to generate a .prop file that gets installed.  See e.g. the list of filenames in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/kitkat-release/libc/include/sys/_system_properties.h .  If it's not in one of those then it's possible that some user-space driver component is setting the property manually.  (I get that you have the answer you need; I'm striving for completeness so the next person who reads this can dig a little deeper.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ro.camera.0.devname is not a property used by AOSP camera code; it's likely specific to some OEM's camera HAL implementation, or to an OEM's custom Android version.

However, to help your search, those properties are often set by the makefiles that define products. For example, for the N5, there's a large number of PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES in the core device definition makefile:

https://android.googlesource.com/device/lge/hammerhead/+/master/device.mk

So perhaps try searching over all the .mk files as well, or just do a full 'repo grep' for that property name?

Comment: You're right... searching for .mk file I found under /device/ directory BoardConfig.mk file that defines those properties.